# Calling a JavaScript function during onchange of a select box

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my view, I have the following:

```
<%= select("event", :event_id, events_ids_titles_hash, { :include_blank => true, :onchange => "alert_me_test()" }) %>
```

alert_me_test() is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function alert_me_test()
  {
      alert ("this is a test")
  }
</script>
```

The dropdown is appearing fine, but when I select from it, nothing happens. I'm expecting an alert box with "this is a test" in it.

## The Edit case:

When I'm doing an edit, I have the following code:

```
<% if @panel.event_id %>
  <%= select("panel", :event_id, events_ids_titles_hash, {:selected => @panel.event_id}, { :include_blank => true}) %>
```

My IDE (RubyMine) does not want to accept the "onchange" as an additional argument, and putting it inside one of the :selected or :include_blank argument hashes does not produce an error, but it does not work either

## What ended up working for both new and edit:

```
<% if @panel.event_id %>
    <%= 'Event is ' + events_ids_titles_hash.key(@panel.event_id) %>
    <%= select("panel", :event_id, events_ids_titles_hash, {:selected => @panel.event_id}, { :include_blank => true, :onchange => "alert_me_test()"}) %>
<% else %>
    <%= 'Select Event from list' %>
    <%= select("event", :event_id, events_ids_titles_hash, { :include_blank => true }, { :onchange => "alert_me_test()" }) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<%= select("event", :event_id, events_ids_titles_hash, { :include_blank => true, :onchange => "alert_me_test()" }) %>
```

Worked for me, but I must say that you are fighting against the current with this one. Rails follows UJS, which means your even handlers should be separate from your HTML. In this case the select would be the same minus the onclick and then the script would be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('select').change(alert_me_test);

  function alert_me_test(){
  ...
  }
</script>
```

You don't have to do things this way, but it makes it clearer when looking at a script where your event calls are coming from.

Comment: It worked for me. The edit worked as well: <%= select("panel", :event_id, events_ids_titles_hash, {:selected => @panel.event_id}, { :include_blank => true, :onchange => "alert_me_test()"}) %> with one issue: the alert is being called twice. Any ideas?

Comment: I am assuming that you used the event handling in the script. In which case you can remove the :onchange=>"alert_me_test()" from the :html hash. Otherwise they will both be triggered.

Comment: In my case, I have to call the function whether I'm editing or not (the actual function is not an alert, but rather an Ajax call to the controller). This means I can't use the more elegent UJS syntax here (though I may be missing something, but I will do more reading on UJS when I free up)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to set the `:onchange` as an HtmlOption, which is a 4th parameter:

```
<%= select("event", :event_id, events_ids_titles_hash, { :include_blank => true}, {:onchange => "alert_me_test()" }) %>
```

Comment: That worked. I still have not figured out the syntax for the edit portion. Please see the edited question above.